# how to create a new solr core in laravel/solarium

Tags: php, laravel, solr, solarium

I am trying to make multi core Solr server and connect from PHP laravel. I did connect the solr and laravel but i cant find a way to create a core. I am also using solarium lib.
Is it possible to create a new core with parameters from php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $solr = SolrClient::factory(array(
            'base_url' => 'http://LOCALHOST:8983',
            'base_path' => '/solr',
        ));
        $response = $solr->get('admin/cores?action=CREATE&name='.$corename.'&instanceDir='.$corename.'&configSet=_default')->send()->json();
```

Imports;

> use PSolr\Client\SolrClient;

This is the solution that i used. I hope it helps someone else.